# iPod nano Bluetooth problems with AirPods

Tags: bluetooth, airpods, ipod-nano

My iPod nano 7th generation gets connected to my AirPods 2nd generation. But when I play songs no sound comes out of it? I tried to reset and run diagnostics but it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 1):

AirPods 2nd generation require the device to be on iOS 12.2 or later, therefore they aren’t compatible with the iPod Nano. The only iPod they are compatible with is the iPod Touch 6th generation.

AirPods 1st generation should work with the iPod Nano though as they don’t have such a system requirement.

The [technical specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP791?locale=en_GB) state:

> #### System Requirements
>
> - iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch models with iOS 12.2 or later

Further down the page the compatible iPod models are:

> #### iPod Models
>
> - iPod touch (6th Generation)